# Rails Nameerror with double namespace controller, namespaced model

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, namespaces, mailboxer

Can't work out how to get around this. I'm using the mailboxer gem, who have recently updated to a namespaced model. Using the main controller, everything is fine, but I also have a namespaced views/controller for an admin section which is causing the issue.

Model name is

```
mailboxer_conversations
```

Main section code (working fine):

routes.rb

```
namespace :mailboxer, path: '', as: nil do
    resources :conversations, only: [:index, :show, :new, :create, :destroy], as: 'conversations', path: 'conversations' do
      member do
        post :reply
        post :trash
        post :untrash
      end
    end
```

controllers/mailboxer/conversations_controller.rb

```
class Mailboxer::ConversationsController < ApplicationController
end
```

The above is all working fine, the controller is namespaced with folders and I can access the Conversation model instance.

The below is the code I'm currently trying for the admin section, using the same model mailboxer_conversations.rb

routes.rb

```
namespace :admin do
    namespace :mailboxer, path: '', as: nil do
      resources :conversations, as: 'conversations', path: 'conversations'
    end
  end
```

controllers/admin/mailboxer/conversations_controller.rb

```
class Admin::Mailboxer::ConversationsController < ApplicationController
end
```

With the above setup, I'm getting a nameerror uninit. constant 'Conversations'. Says to me that it can't access the model, is this because of the double namespace, it's expecting the model.rb file to be in a different folder i.e admin/mailboxer_conversations.rb? I can't move the model, as it's in a gem.

Thanks

Comment: You use inherited_resources or something? Most likely you'll need to specify a class name. `load_and_authorize_resource class_name: 'blah blah'`

Comment: "convention over configuration", that's why. cancan was trying to infer class names for you.

Comment: I see, convention over configuration strikes again. Thanks for the help. Add it in as the answer and I'll mark correct